# How to write ca-certificate via terminal in one line?

Tags: terminal, at-command

I am working with a mobile network module via AT commands.
HTTPS requests are working fine. However I do struggle to enter the ca-cert correctly.
I am quite certain that this is some simple fault of mine.

Normally the PEM encoded cert would be like this:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIFFjCCAv6gXXXXXXXRAJErCErPDBinU/bWLiWnX1owDQYJKoZIhvcNAQELBQAw
...
AoYWaHR0cDovL3gxLmkubGVuY3Iub3JnLzAnBgNVHR8EIDAeMBygGqAYhhZodHRw
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

So to make it a one-liner I transformed it to this:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\nMIIFFjCCAv6gXXXXXXXRAJErCErPDBinU/bWLiWnX1owDQYJKoZIhvcNAQELBQAw\n...AoYWaHR0cDovL3gxLmkubGVuY3Iub3JnLzAnBgNVHR8EIDAeMBygGqAYhhZodHRw\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n
```

This was my attempt in sending the whole certificate in one string as needed by the module (Adrastea 1). I was using the given terminal tool by the manufacturer but also putty. In both cases I could not make to send multi-line AT commands. Neither with shift+Enter nor with a copied commands into Putty.

The feedback I get from the module is pretty narrow, it accepts the commmand itself with an OK, but this only means that the syntax of the command is correct, not specifically the certificate I provided. When I try to request an HTTPS website afterwards the module crashes and restart, so there should be definetly something wrong with the way I inserted the certificate.

This is the whole command I send to write the cert to a file. I shorted and changed the certificate of course

```
AT%CERTCMD="WRITE","certificate1.pem",0,\r\n"-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\nMIIFFjCCAv6gAwIBAgIRAJErCErPDBinU/bWLiWnX1owDQYJKoZIhvcNAQELBQAw\nPTNlclQtgaDqw+34IL9fzLdwALduO/ZelN7kIJ+m74uyA+eitRY8kc607TkC53wl\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n"
```

Comment: Talking about the question itself, sinse I don't have an Adrastea module to test, I can just provide some speculations: 1) talking in general, the position of LFs in PEM certificates should not be important except for BEGIN/END markers, as it is just base 64 encoded data. 2) modules should never crash, even in case of malformed data (that's probably your case). 3) You "correctly" put CR-LF before data, as suggested by the AT guide, but **I suspect it's a documental bug**,  ... _[continued]_

Comment: ... because it the later examples of the [guide](https://www.we-online.com/katalog/media/o691492v8984%20Manual-um-acm-adrastea-i-2615011136000-V1-0%20%28rev1%29.pdf) they are omitted. If my assumption is correct, that could someway truncate the stored certificate (or maybe junk is stored instead of the actual certificate) causing the later crash. This command has a strange design, to say the least, as _data mode_ is usually a better choice for transferring to a module long inputs like certificates (like in commands such as `AT+CMGS`, used to send SMSs).

Comment: What do you mean with "the module crashes and restart"? As said by @RobertoCaboni, modules should never crash, I'm able to make my modules crash (Quectel or Telit) when I try a network request (like network registration) or other power-consuming commands and the module haven't enough power (undevoltage), so MAYBE that's not a problem related to the certificate itself.

Comment: @Majico I wasn't clear on the fact that modules should never crash... but sometimes they do because they might have bugs and/or lack in robustness in case of malformed input.  In this case, probably, an error should have been returned after cert write command.

Comment: @RobertoCaboni Thank you for yours answer. I was quite frustrated by the dowvotes I got. Thank you for confiring the right use of the Line Feed. 
I read quite a few ties over the part of the documentation but could not find any further information on this. On some page it is mentioned, that the LF character is needed in front of the certificate as well. Got to try different versions I guess.

Comment: Did removing that CR-LF work? If it does, I can turn my comments into an answer. If it doesn't let's try to understand why

Comment: No it did not unfortunately. I am at the point where I think  I tried every possible combination, with CR-LF, without it, Without the Leading CR-LF that is mentioned in the docs to put in front of the cert-string.
What is kind of interesting tho is the fact that they mad a little mistake further down where you do the HTTP config. Just a small thing, however this made me lose trust in believing that the docs are correct on this command as well.

Comment: @RobertoCaboni I found out, when I use the same command as I mentioned in the question and try to read it afterwards, it shows me the cert in the terminal in a single line with \n inside. So it seems like the module did not interpret the LF correctly ? I the docs, the exaple is the exact same however their document it as if the odule would give me a multi-line answer . 
However something like "AT%CERTCMD="WRITE","test.pem",0,\r\n"---Beign\n\rredfe\n\rdfsdf"" does not work at all. Only get an Error back but have to test, how to correctly give him a new line.

Comment: @Ric I probably know what it happens: the module doesn't escape `\n` so it probably wants an actual line feed character. Try writing it by hand, and when it comes to LF write it to Putty with Alt+10

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252016/discussion-between-ric-and-roberto-caboni).